# how to assign a property of an object to another property of another object using method inside third object with arguments pointing to two objects

Tags: excel, vba, class, methods, properties

VBA question, it may sounds complicated question but the general idea is as follows:

i have a class called 'square' with properties 'inputA', 'inputB' as write only and 'outputA', 'outputB' which are read only.

I also have a class called 'triangle' with properties 'inputA', 'inputB', 'outputA', 'outputB' also as above.

and I also have a class called 'circle' with same properties as above. each class does different things with inputs and pass it to the outputs.

I have created a class called 'link' with method called 'link_between' with two arguments 'object1' and 'object2' pointing to objects created from classes above.

link class method goes like this:

```
Sub link_between(new_object1 As Object, new_object2 As Object)

     Dim object1, object2
     Set object1 = new_object1
     Set object2 = new_object2

     Set object2.inputA = object1.outputA
     Set object2.inputB = object1.outputB
End Sub
```

the purpose of this method is that I want to use it to link properties of different objects, like 'square' and 'triangle' or 'triangle' and 'circle' just by referencing them in method.

unfortunately I get an error **'Object doesn't support this property or method'.** the objects are visible inside method, as these are public objects

the sub to instantiate link object is:

```
Sub CommandButton4_Click()
     Set link1 = New link
     link1.link_between square_1, triangle_1
End Sub
```

the class 'link' is there so I can create multiple links between objects.

any help will be appreciated since I can not figure out why properties of the objects can not be assigned in this way

I have also tried to use actual objects as arguments:

```
Sub link_between(new_object1 As square, new_object2 As triangle)
```

but this did not help either.

I hope someone did it before and would be able to help me understand what I am doing wrong. I could not find any similar question on this forum or anything that would help me.

Comment: Did you really name the property `inputB`? It's a reserved identifiers.

Comment: the name of the property is does not matter, it was used here only to indicate a purpose of property, anyway, I sorted this one out so I am closing this question. turns out I used incorrect name for my properties in class 'link'. so good news: code is working now as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I used incorrect name for my properties in class 'link'. so good news: code is working now as intended.